# Verb form for Didactic

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs, nouns

What are possible verb forms or more proper forms for the word *didactic*? I know that *didact* is only a noun, although audiologically it sounds as though it could be a verb. The sentence I am trying to fit it into is:

> The advertising industry attempts to [didact] this specious ideal of beauty to women.

One of the main reasons that the word *didacti*c really drew my attention was it is defined as intended to teach, particularly in having moral instruction **as an ulterior motive**.

Comment: _ *promulgate* ?_

Comment: The normal word is **teach**.

Comment: One of the main reasons that the word didactic really drew my attention was it is defined as intended to teach, particularly in having moral instruction **as an ulterior motive**

Comment: Not a true synonym, but I like "... **foist** [x] **on** [y]."

Comment: As I read this, I immediately thought of the word "indoctrinate." So that probably has broader appeal for your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fourth edition (2000) gives three definitions for didactic:

> **didactic** also **didactical** *adj.* **1.** Intended to instruct. **2.** Morally instructive. **3.** Inclined to teach or moralize excessively.

None of these definitions explicitly includes the note of teaching with an ulterior motive that you mention in a comment above, but the third definition, with its emphasis on teaching or moralizing excessively may hint at something similar.

A number of verbs can be used to indicate teaching to serve an ulterior motive. A usage note at *implant* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) offers a close comparison of several verbs that are candidates for the meaning that you may have in mind:

> IMPLANT, INCULCATE, INSTILL, INSEMINATE, INFIX means to introduce into the mind. IMPLANT implies teaching that makes for permanence of what is taught [example omitted]. INCULCATE implies persistent or repeated efforts to impress on the mind [example omitted]. INSTILL stresses gradual, gentle imparting of knowledge over a long period of time [example omitted]. INSEMINATE applies to a sowing of ideas in many minds so that they spread through a class or nation [example omitted]. INFIX stresses firmly inculcating a habit of thought [example omitted].

The definition closest to what you describe seems to be the one for *inseminate*, although that word seems so closely connected to procreation in most people's minds that it may not work for you. My own preference is for *inculcate*, which emphasizes the persistence of the effort—and which does not imply anything about the intentions (and motives) of the inculcator, for good or for ill.

However, I think that the verb that may most accurately describe the process of teaching a belief for ulterior purposes is *indoctrinate*. Here is the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s definition of that word:

> **indoctrinate** *vt* (1626) **1 :** to instruct esp. in fundamentals or rudiments : TEACH **2 :** to imbue with a usu. partisan or sectarian opinion, point of view, or principle

The second definition here is the one that I think fits best in your example sentence, though it requires as light adjustment of the final part of the sentence:

> The advertising industry attempts to indoctrinate women with this specious ideal of beauty.

Answer (score 1):

Any synonym for "teach" works, really.

Regarding your example sentence, I think "promote" or "instil" fits well, although normally we hear about the advertising industry trying to "sell" the ideal of beauty to women more than teach anything.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term *[inculcate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/inculcate)*

> Instill (an attitude, idea, or habit) by persistent instruction:
>   *the failures of the churches to inculcate a sense of moral responsibility*

*Oxford Dicitionary Online*

It seems to mesh well with the *ODO's* definition of *[didactic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/didactic)*

> Intended to teach, particularly in having moral instruction as an ulterior motive:
>   *a didactic novel that set out to expose social injustice*

Comment: *Inculcate* is a good answer, but do you really think a novel (read presumably once) can instil by persistent instruction?

Comment: @TimLymington The examples given are those of ODO, so I don't get to choose. But I do think a novel, read once, can attempt to hit you over the head with a persistent theme or concept. To Wolfe, for example, often uses phrases over and over to describe something he disdains. I think he is attempting to inculcate that point of view in the reader.

Comment: In my case, the advertisements are not just read once they are constantly teaching this belief and social construct. So, I believe that inculcate would be perfect, thank you all!